# Getting the width of a Chunk does not include the last character

Tags: itext

I am rendering 3 characters to the bottom left of a PDF document. I am doing this by creating a Column and then positioning the column accordingly with the correct dimensions to match the Chunk (or in this case, Paragraph)

If you run the following code in LINQPad (or anywhere really) you'll see that the 'Z' character is missing from the output and I can't work out why. The X axis is set to the same width as the width of the chunk.

```
 var pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (pdfDocument)
    {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, ms))
        {
            pdfDocument.Open();

            pdfDocument.NewPage();

            var cb = writer.DirectContent;

            var font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16);

            var chunk = new Chunk("XYZ", font);

            float textWidth = chunk.GetWidthPoint();

            var p = new Paragraph(chunk);

            var ct = new ColumnText(cb);

            ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, textWidth, p.TotalLeading);

            ct.AddElement(p);
            ct.Go();

            pdfDocument.Close();
        }
    }
    var tmpPdfPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".pdf";

    File.WriteAllBytes(tmpPdfPath, ms.ToArray());

    Process.Start(tmpPdfPath);
}
```

Comment: iText works with `float` values internally. This means that there might be some rounding errors. Didn't you notice that 0.1 * 10 equals 1, but 0.1f * 10f equals 0.9999f in some cases?

Comment: Yes but I'm not adding anything. I'm asking iText for the width of a chunk. Shouldn't it give me the correct answer?

Comment: iText is adding up `float` values: one for each character.